# Trying to set color to my text in android

Tags: android, colors

I am trying to set color for my text in android. Every time i launch my application it shuts down. Here is what i have in color.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<color name="background_color">#006400</color>
<color name="app_text_color">#FFE4C4</color>
```

here is what i have in my MainActivity Class:

```
int textColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.app_text_color);

        TextView helloText = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.hello_world);

        helloText.setTextColor(textColor);
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
         />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log Car:

```
04-17 21:00:39.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1670)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
TextView helloText = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.hello_world);
```

you have to use some ID in findViewByID, like

```
TextView helloText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
```

here your_textview_id is the id of your textview in layout xml..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_textview_id"
     .............
      .........
```

I just tried this and it worked for me:

```
TextView helloText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world);

helloText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_text_color));
```

Comment: it still didn't work for some reason the application keep forcing a close

Comment: and logcat data also for crash report

Comment: you must set layout using setCoententView befoe initiating TextView. Have you done that?

Comment: Can you give me a example on how to use setContentView

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); just put this in oncreate at the beginning